# How can I share a file using react-native and expo on android without detaching?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on an app with Expo and would like the user be able to share a file (.vcf) with an application of their choice.

On iOS I have this working without issues using the default

```
Share.share({url: filetoshare})
```

However, the URL field only works for iOS. I read a suggestion to use

```
IntentLauncherAndroid.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.SEND', {URI 
: uri});
```

But this gives me the error:

```
No Activity Found To Handle Intent
```

Is there any way that I would be able to share a file without detaching on an android device?

If there is any additional information I could provide to make answering this question easier, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding `file://` to the uri for Android only?